# How many relations can you form that are Range = $B$, $A=\{1,2,..,n\}$,$B =\{1,2,..,m\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

How many relations can you form the are Range = $B$, $A=\{1,2,..,n\}$,$B =\{1,2,..,m\}$, and $m \ge n$

From my understanding, ALL THE elements in $B$ must be in the right spot of the relation. for example (1,1),(1,2),...,(1,m) for element "1" in "A". last one is (n,1),(n,2),..,(n,m).

I think that the answer would be, $n^m$ are number of pairs we can form, and $2^{n^m}$ are number of relations we can form if $ n = m $.
otherwise, if $ m > n$ then we have $m - n$ elements left, and we have $2^{m-n} + 2^{n^m}$ relations.

What do you guys think?

**Edit: check my solution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the maps from $B$ to $P(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ which has cardinality
$$
\left(2^n-1\right)^m
$$
since the cardinality of $P(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}=2^n-1$.

Note that $P(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ is just the collection of non-empty subsets of $A$ as stated by drhab.

---

The number of *functions* from $B$ to $A$ is $n^m$, but the question asks for *relations* whose range is $B$.

Comment: Aww, I'm upset that this is the answer. It makes sense though. :(

Comment: I've uploaded my teacher's solution for the exam. can you take a look and verify why your answer is wrong? or maybe both answers are correct.

Comment: Yes. As drhab points out, the binomial theorem says that your instructor's answer is the same as ours.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly then $R\subseteq A\times B$ such that for every $b\in B$ there is some $a\in A$ with $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$.

So for every $b\in B$ the set $\{a\in A\mid \langle a,b\rangle\in R\}$ is allowed to be any non-empty subset of $A$ and is not allowed to be empty.

The number of nonempty subsets of $A$ is $2^n-1$.

That gives: $$(2^n-1)^m$$ possibilities for $R$.

I don't understand the role of condition $m\geq n$, so still have doubts about my understanding.

Comment: I hope you are wrong, it was a question from my exam :(

Comment: Here is my empathy: :(-

Comment: Anyways, I still didn't understand your answer. can you give an example with some elements of $A$ and $B$ and prove that what you are saying is true?

Comment: Time lacks now, later I will have a second look.

Comment: @drhab: thanks for the correction to my answer.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Everything clear now? If not, then let me know please.

Comment: @drhab still dont answer why there is an emepty set we need to substract.

Comment: Every subset $R\subseteq A\times B$ is a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Formal_definition). The range of the relation is a subset of $B$. An element $b\in B$ will belong to the range of $R$ if there is an element $a\in A$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$. In your question it is demanded that every $b\in B$ belongs to the range of $R$. So for every $b\in B$ there must be an $a\in A$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$. That can reformulated: for every $b\in B$ the set $\{a\in A\mid\langle a,b\rangle\in R\}$ is not allowed to be empty.

Comment: @drhab I've uploaded my teacher's solution for the exam. can you take a look and verify why your answer is wrong? or maybe both answers are correct.

Comment: My answer appears to be correct (see my comment on your answer). The switch of $m$ and $n$ is not our mistake. Show this (more simple and elegant) answer to your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution for my exam, and the answer to that question is as I expected during the exam because it was 14 points. what do you guys think? did you solve it wrong?

[image]

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{i}\binom{n}{i}2^{m\left(n-i\right)}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\left(-1\right)^{i}\left(2^{m}\right)^{n-i}=\left(\left(-1\right)+2^{m}\right)^{n}=\left(2^{m}-1\right)^{n}$. The $m$ and $n$ are switched, but that is not my mistake.

Comment: @drhab: Yes. It appears the instructor failed to simplify their answer.

Comment: The answers are equal. The inclusion-exclusion answer is correct, but more complicated.